# Joomla - Blank User Manager screen in control panel

Tags: joomla

I have moved a Joomla installation over to a new server using Akeeba Backup, everything has gone fine and everything appears to work.  But if I select User Manager from the Control Panel I am presented with a blank white screen.

I have followed the error checking steps at http://www.phil-taylor.com/2009/01/12/a-blank-white-page-is-still-an-error-page but still havent been able to see any problems.

The Access logs show me trying to access the page and it returns with a code 200.  I have disabled all modules and reverted back to a stock theme.

Can anyone help out or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a backup of the old site without using Akeeba Backup. Simply zip the contents of the root folder and upload to the new server. Export the database using PHPMyAdmin or via the backup manager if you have cPanel, then upload to the new server.

Answer (score 0):

Try Reinstalling after backing up the database....And do check for the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

A white screen usually indicates an error. Try turning your error reporting to maximum or development and see if you get any messages.